# Cannot update the project in android ndk

Tags: android

I'm using linux and i have successfully installed ndk and configured it. with the help of [Android NDK installation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) But i can't able to generate build.xml file

```
root@ndot-173:~/Desktop/NDK4/samples/bitmap-plasma# android update project -p . -s
android: command not found
```

It shows command not found.
How do i generate build.xml file..?

Comment: Sounds like a PATH-issue. Make sure the `android`-executable is in your PATH.

Comment: @bos.Thanks for your pleasant response.But how could i check the path.? I mean i don't have sound knowledge in it..? Could you please share something about it. **Any link..?**

Comment: In the shell of your choice, enter `echo $PATH`. Make sure the path to the SDK-binaries are in it. If not, alter it in your shell's rc-file.

Comment: **root@ndot-173:~/android-sdks/platform-tools# ./adb shell
# echo $PATH
/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
#** I really donno what is RC file.? I guess i'm annoying you. but this is the fact, Eager to know., I got the above result. What should i do now..?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add android sdk in you PATH or

you use the absolute path of the android command ex: you_android_sdk_path/tools/android